# Kafka Listener is giving ClassCastException

Tags: java, spring, spring-kafka

I have a kafka listener, which receives the data correctly but `EventData ss = consumerRecord.value()` gives ClassCastException.

I am using default spring boot settings.
I am not sure how it receives the message correctly and when I try to use, it gives the exception.

```
 @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.event.model.message}")
    public void receive(ConsumerRecord<String, EventData> consumerRecord)  throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        LOGGER.info("received payload='{}'", consumerRecord.value());
        EventData ss = consumerRecord.value();
    }
```

It gives the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.betstars.betsyncadapter.app.kafka.message.EventData
    at com.betstars.betsyncadapter.app.kafka.message.KafkaMessageListenerForEventModel.receive(KafkaMessageListenerForEventModel.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:180) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:112) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:48) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:174) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

Comment: do you have JSON Desrializer configured? checkout my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48502892/how-to-serialize-object-to-json-ad-hoc-in-spring/48503219#48503219

Comment: Hi @pvpkiran, if listener receives it correctly, how does it give exception to receiving it? Also, if I have tried using your example, I got the below exception `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition eventModelTopic-0 at offset 0
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't deserialize data [[69, ....]] from topic [eventModelTopic]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'EventData': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')`

Comment: listner recieves the event. But in Json String form, which needs to be desrialized to your custom type. At that point it is failing. Can you show how did you write your deserializer

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot Apache Kafka auto-configuration uses `StringDeserializer` for the `value` by default:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.0.0.RC1/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/kafka/KafkaProperties.java#L287

You should consider to use a `org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer` for your `EventData` use-case:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.value.default.type=com.your.EventData
```

That's for the Spring Boot `2.0` though.

For the previous version you should use a `JsonDeserializer` extension:

```
public class EventDataJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<EventData> { }
```

for the property:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer = com.your.EventDataJsonDeserializer
```

Answer (score 0):

Also double check if you configure "properties.specific.avro.reader: true" for your consumer